# Discord.py - Discord not processing @client.command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently learning python (slowly) and have started writing a discord bot. However, when i call a @client.command function nothing happens in discord. For example .ping should reply with "pong!" but nothing happens and I do not get an error.

My code is below

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import discord.client


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

messages = joined = 0
bad_words = ["example"]
channel = ["general"]


@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, userName: discord.Member):
    await client.kick(userName)


@client.event(message)
async def on_ready():
    id = client.get_guild(705455096749752323)
    print("hello")


async def update_stats():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    global messages, joined
    while not client.is_closed():
        try:
            with open("stats.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(f"""Messages: {messages}, Members Joined {joined}, time: {time.time()}\n""")

            messages = 0
            joined = 0

            await  asyncio.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    n = after.nick
    if n:
        if n.lower().count("Crysis Wolfie") > 0:
            last = before.nick
            if last:
                await after.edit(nick=last)
            else:
                await after.edit(nick="NO STOP THAT!")


@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    n = after.game
    if n:
        if n.lower.count(f"""{before.n}""") > 0:
            discord.message.channel.send()


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global joined
    joined += 1
    for channel in member.server.channels:
        if str(channel) == "general":
            await discord.message.channel_send(f"""Welcome to the server {member.mention}""")


@client.event
async def on_message(message, yes=None):
    # chat commands
    id = client.get_guild(705455096749752323)
    channels = ["general", "apply"]
    global messages
    messages = + 1
    if str(message.channel) in channels:
        if message.content.find("!hello") != -1:
            await message.channel.send(f"""What's cooking {message.author.mention} looking good today :wink:""")
        elif message.content == "!users":
            await message.channel.send(f"""Number of members {id.member_count}""")
        if message.content.find("NHS") != -1:
            await message.channel.send("https://tenor.com/view/goodjob-clap-nicework-great-gif-7248435")
        if message.content.find("wolfie") != -1:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            await message.channel.send("https://tenor.com/view/facepalm-really-stressed-mad-angry-gif-16109475")
        if message.content.find("crysis") != -1:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            await message.channel.send("https://tenor.com/view/facepalm-really-stressed-mad-angry-gif-16109475")
        if message.content.find("!apply") != -1:
            await message.channel.send(f"""TESTING""")
        for word in bad_words:
            if message.content.count(word) > 0:
                await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
                await message.channel.send(f"""User {message.author.mention} watch your language!""")
                try:
                    with open("badwordlog.txt", "a") as n:
                        n.write(f"""member: {message.author}, said {message.content}, at {time.time()}\n""")
                        print(f"""member: {message.author}, said {message.content}""");
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
await client.process_commands(message)
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):  # needs fixing
    n = before.status
    if n != before:
        await discord.message.channel.send(f"""have fun on {after} """)


@client.command()
async def create_invite(self, ctx):  # needs fixing
    self = bot
    """Create invite"""
    link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=300)
    await ctx.send("Here is an instant invite to your server: " + link)


@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong!')
clint.run('my token is here but I have removed')
```

@client.event functions run fine and work great! But client.command does nothing :(.

thanks

Comment: Without any knowledge of discord API ... shouldn't the decorator be `@client.command` instead of `@client.command()`

Comment: Looked into the API: apparently if you override `on_message` you need to call `process_commands` at the end; see the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

Comment: Hmm, I tried both and neither worked. I then removed on_ready and still nothing

Comment: Can you update your post showing where you added **process_commands** in the **on_message** function?

Comment: I have updated, I have put it right at the bottoms under the last if

Comment: Hmm ... the updated content makes it look like it's on the same indentation level as the function definitions which is not OK. It should be on the same level as `messages = + 1` and the `if` after it.

Comment: That has worked :D